# How to quckly copy text from running app activity?

Tags: applications

There is running 3rd party app, random text appears every minute on screen. I need to quickly copy text, immediately after it appeared.
root, xposed and etc. are provided.

Answer (score 0):

It is not stated which Android version or device. So, assumption is that the app is user friendly.

When the text appear, **long press** on the text until the edit text context menu appears. Choose select all, then choose copy. Can be done under 6 seconds.

Later you can paste and edit the text required.